Div float left, div float right
Hello guys be kind I'm new to programming.
I just started doing some stuff to practice so I created a little web site. I created a div container with a display block for the ul 'home, service, ecc..' on the top of the container and then two div. one to the left with float left and one to the right with float right. The problem is that i made them 70% and 30% width but won't fix in the container. The only way is to make the right one width 26.9% and that's hilarious because I can even see the little space left between them. Also if i make them height: 100% they will both go down outside the container, how do I make them the same height as the container? I would like to use the % so that it can be as responsive as it can.
I tried everything I could to fix them in the container. I just can't see the problem.
Here's the code


.container {
    display: block;
    border: solid black 1px;
    width: 70%;
    height: 1000px;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-right: 15%;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
article {
    float: left;
    border: solid black 1px;
    width: 70%;
    height: auto;
}
aside {
    float: right;
    border: solid black 1px;
    width: 29.6%;
    height: auto;
}
    <div class="container">
        <nav>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Servizi</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contattaci</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Iscriviti</a></li>
            </ul>    
        </nav>
        <article>
            <h1>Lorem</h1>
            <p>Lorem</p>
            <br>
            <p>Lorem50</p>
        </article>
        <aside>
            <ul class="sideTitles">
                <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
            </ul>
        </aside>
    </div>




Just add article, aside {   box-sizing: border-box; } and you can use 70% and 30%.

this sort of thing is simply done using a flexbox.

Just add box-sizing: border-box; to all elements to include the borders in the widths, which are otherwise added  to the widths by default:


.container {
    display: block;
    border: solid black 1px;
    width: 70%;
    height: 1000px;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-right: 15%;
    margin-top: 40px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
article {
    float: left;
    border: solid black 1px;
    width: 70%;
    height: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
aside {
    float: right;
    border: solid black 1px;
    width: 29.6%;
    height: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
<div class="container">
        <nav>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Servizi</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contattaci</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Iscriviti</a></li>
            </ul>    
        </nav>
        <article>
            <h1>Lorem</h1>
            <p>Lorem</p>
            <br>
            <p>Lorem50</p>
        </article>
        <aside>
            <ul class="sideTitles">
                <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
            </ul>
        </aside>
    </div>




This was so helpful! Thanks alot! What about the height? I want it to be high as the container but when i wright height:100% it goes further than the main box.

If you use height:100% on an element, the parent element  needs to have a defined height. If the parent element also has height:100%, the parent of the parent element needs to have a defined height etc. If you only use percentages for height, you need to start with height:100% on body  and html and all elements in between those and the desired element.

Oh... that's new. So what's your advice? I tried to use % so that everything can be easly responsive but I'd like to take the best way to do things. BTW the parent element in this case is div container that has 1000px height, am I missing something?

If the parent has 1000px height defined, 100% of that is 1000px... But if you want a unit that is relative to the browser window height, use 100vh, which is exactly the height of the browser window.

Ok now I understood everything. I just needed the article and the aside to be enough high to occupy the rest of the container.

You need to use Flexbox layout as it has made the responsive page creation much easier and also solves your problem as the following example:


.container {
    display: flex;
    border: solid black 1px;
    width: 70%;
    height: 1000px;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-right: 15%;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
article {
    border: solid black 1px;
    width: 70%;
    height: auto;
}
aside {
    border: solid black 1px;
    width: 29.6%;
    height: auto;
}
 <div class="container">
    <nav>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Servizi</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contattaci</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Iscriviti</a></li>
        </ul>    
    </nav>
    <article>
        <h1>Lorem</h1>
        <p>Lorem</p>
        <br>
        <p>Lorem50</p>
    </article>
    <aside>
        <ul class="sideTitles">
            <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
        </ul>
    </aside>
</div>




There's no need to use flexbox, even though it may be a good choice to do so.

Unfortunately if I use flexbox the 3 boxes appears in column. I need the nav to be on top o the two (article and aside)
